# Solve with inverse trig functions (4-Bar Linkage)

Tags: equation-solving

```
    c = 5.; b = 3.; a = 2.; len = 7.5;
u[t_] := Reduce[
  NSolve[(2 c + a Cos[t] - b Cos[u[t]])^2 + (a Sin[t] - b Sin[u[t]])^2 - 
     len^2 == 0], u, Reals]
Plot[u[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Please help to obtain a simplified output using Reduce. (4-Bar linkage).

[image]

Comment: You're not using NSolve properly - which variable are you solving for?

Comment: Sorry, u[t] corrected typo

Comment: `NSolve[(2 c + a Cos[t] - b Cos[u[t]])^2 + (a Sin[t] - b Sin[u[t]])^2 - len^2 == 0]` this still doesn't work. What variable are you solving for?

Comment: You are defining a procedural function `u[t_]` using the expression `u[t]` symbolically in its definition. This is not a sensible use of recursion. What problem are you trying to solve, exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `Reduce` , try Weirstrass substitution  `u[t] -> 2 ArcTan[uu]`:

Leaving the parameters undefined try

```
eq = TrigExpand[(2 c + a Cos[t] - b Cos[u[t]])^2 + (a Sin[t] - 
   b Sin[u[t]])^2 - len^2 == 0]
sol = 2 ArcTan[uu] /.Solve[eq /. u[t] -> 2 ArcTan[uu] // TrigExpand, uu]
```

which gives the two solution branches u[t] in analytical form.
`{2 ArcTan[(4 a b Sin[ t] - \[Sqrt](-4 (a^2 + b^2 - 4 b c + 4 c^2 - len^2 -  2 a b Cos[t] + 4 a c Cos[t]) (a^2 + b^2 + 4 b c + 4 c^2 -  len^2 + 2 a b Cos[t] + 4 a c Cos[t]) +  16 a^2 b^2 Sin[t]^2))/(2 (a^2 + b^2 + 4 b c + 4 c^2 -  len^2 + 2 a b Cos[t] + 4 a c Cos[t]))],  2 ArcTan[(4 a b Sin[ t] + \[Sqrt](-4 (a^2 + b^2 - 4 b c + 4 c^2 - len^2 -  2 a b Cos[t] + 4 a c Cos[t]) (a^2 + b^2 + 4 b c + 4 c^2 -  len^2 + 2 a b Cos[t] + 4 a c Cos[t]) +  16 a^2 b^2 Sin[t]^2))/(2 (a^2 + b^2 + 4 b c + 4 c^2 -  len^2 + 2 a b Cos[t] + 4 a c Cos[t]))]}`

```
Plot[sol /. {c -> 5, b -> 3, a -> 2, len -> 15/2} //Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]tps://i.stack.imgur.com/dEkDP.png

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = 5; b = 3; a = 2; len = 15/2;

eqn = (2 c + a Cos[t] - b Cos[u])^2 + (a Sin[t] - b Sin[u])^2 - 
    len^2 == 0 // Simplify

(* 227/4 + 40 Cos[t] == 12 (Cos[t - u] + 5 Cos[u]) *)

sol = u /. 
    Assuming[0 <= t <= 2 Pi, 
     Solve[{eqn, 0 <= t < 2 Pi}, u, Reals, Method -> Reduce] // 
      Simplify] /. C[1] -> 0;

u1[t_] = sol[[1]]
```

[image]

```
u2[t_] = sol[[2]]
```

[image]

```
FunctionDomain[#[t], t] & /@ {u1, u2}
```

[image]

```
%[[1]] // N

3.14159 < t < 4.86928 || 1.4139 < t < 3.14159

Plot[{u1[t], u2[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotLegends -> Placed[{u1, u2}, {0.85, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

For comparison,

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn,
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, -1.35, 1.35},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do we include the second solution (  with U looking up? )

Comment: See edit. You must define two functions since a function cannot be multivalued for any argument.