# Regarding the interactive operation of a four-bar linkage mechanism

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, animation, simulation

[image: 1]

I have a four-bar linkage mechanism, where when the left locator is moved, the right locator moves accordingly, and when the right locator is moved, the left locator moves accordingly. I have implemented this using `DynamicModule` + `Locator`:

```
Clear["`*"]; ptX = {0, 0}; p = 3;
DynamicModule[{}, {C1, r1} = {{0, 0}, 2};
 {C2, r2} = {{3, 0}, 2}; {p1, p2} = {{0, 2}, {3.5, 2}};
 Graphics[{{Thickness[.003], Darker@Green, Line[{p1, p2} // Dynamic]},
   {Thickness[.003], Orange, Line[{p2, {p, 0}} // Dynamic]},
   {Thickness[.003], Blue, 
    Line[{ptX, p1} // 
      Dynamic]}, {ParametricPlot[{{2 Cos[u], 2 Sin[u]}, {2 Cos[u] + 3,
         2 Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}][[1]]}, {Locator[
     Dynamic[p1, (p1 = C1 + r1 Normalize[# - C1]; 
        sola = Solve[
            EuclideanDistance[
               p1, {2 Cos[\[Phi]b0] + 3, 2 Sin[\[Phi]b0]}] == 3.5 && 
             0 <= \[Phi]b0 <= 2 Pi, \[Phi]b0, Reals][[1]] // Quiet; 
        p2 = {2 Cos[\[Phi]b0] + 3, 2 Sin[\[Phi]b0]} /. sola) &]], 
    Locator[Dynamic[
      p2, (p2 = C2 + r2 Normalize[# - C2]; 
        solb = Solve[
            EuclideanDistance[
               p2, {2 Cos[\[Phi]a0], 2 Sin[\[Phi]a0]}] == 3.5 && 
             0 <= \[Phi]a0 <= 2 Pi, \[Phi]a0, Reals][[1]] // Quiet; 
        p1 = {2 Cos[\[Phi]a0], 2 Sin[\[Phi]a0]} /. solb) &]]}},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 8}, {-5, 7}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 420], 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Now I want to use the `Manipulate` function along with slidebars to complete this coupled system. Slidebar 1 controls the coordinates (rotation angle) of the left locator, and slidebar 2 controls the coordinates (rotation angle) of the right locator. Moving one slidebar should affect the other slidebar. How can I implement this operation?

The final goal is to create an animation: after the blue link rotates counterclockwise by a certain angle, the orange link rotates clockwise by a certain angle.

Comment: Similar: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40570/how-can-i-simulate-this-toggle-mechanism

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["`*"]; c = 12/2; b = 9; a = 9; len = 9;
eqa = TrigExpand[(2 c + a Cos[u[t]] - b Cos[t])^2 + (a Sin[u[t]] - 
        b Sin[t])^2 - len^2 == 0];
sola = 2 ArcTan[uu] /. 
    Solve[eqa /. u[t] -> 2 ArcTan[uu] // TrigExpand, uu] // Quiet;
a1[t_] = sola[[1]]; a2[t_] = sola[[2]];
eqb = TrigExpand[(2 c + a Cos[t] - b Cos[u[t]])^2 + (a Sin[t] - 
        b Sin[u[t]])^2 - len^2 == 0];
solb = 2 ArcTan[uu] /. 
    Solve[eqb /. u[t] -> 2 ArcTan[uu] // TrigExpand, uu] // Quiet;
b1[t_] = solb[[1]]; b2[t_] = solb[[2]];
plotb = Plot[{b2[t], b1[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
plota = Plot[{a2[t], a1[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
{plota, plotb}
origin = {0, 0}; list = {};
Manipulate[
 Which[action == "Rotate Blue", 
  Which[funca == "a1", \[Phi]b = a1[\[Phi]a], 
   funca == "a2", \[Phi]b = a2[\[Phi]a]],
  action == "Rotate orange", 
  Which[funcb == "b1", \[Phi]a = b1[\[Phi]b], 
   funcb == "b2", \[Phi]a = b2[\[Phi]b]]]; 
 p2 = {a Cos[\[Phi]b] + 2 c, a Sin[\[Phi]b]};
 p1 = {b Cos[\[Phi]a], b Sin[\[Phi]a]}; mid = (p1 + p2)/2;
 solp3 = Solve[
    EuclideanDistance[mid, {x, y}] == 4 && 
     Dot[p1 - p2, mid - {x, y}] == 0, {x, y}, Reals] // Quiet;
 p3 = Sort[{x, y} /. solp3, 
    EuclideanDistance[#1, {0, 0}] > EuclideanDistance[#2, {0, 0}] &][[
   1]]; AppendTo[list, p3]; 
 Show[Graphics[{{Transparent, Circle[{0, 0}, b + 1], 
     Circle[{2 c, 0}, a + 1]}, {Point[p3], Line[{p3, p2}], 
     Line[{p3, p1}], Thickness[.003], Darker@Green, Line[{p1, p2}], 
     Thickness[.003], Orange, Line[{p2, {2 c, 0}}], Thickness[.003], 
     Blue, Line[{origin, p1}]}},
   PlotRange -> All(*{{-5,8},{-5,7}}*), Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 420], 
  ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Red]], {{\[Phi]a, 0, "Blue"}, -Pi, 
  2 Pi, .1, Appearance -> "Open"}, {{\[Phi]b, 2.88, "orange"}, -Pi, 
  2 Pi, .1, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 Control[{{action, "Rotate Blue", "action"}, {"Rotate Blue", 
    "Rotate orange"}}], 
 Control[{{funca, "a1", "funca"}, {"a1", "a2"}}], 
 Control[{{funcb, "b2", "funcb"}, {"b1", "b2"}}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Top, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {\[Phi]a, \[Phi]b}]
```

[image: 1]
reference: [Solve with inverse trig functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226423/86487)